# How to add a panel in between two divs in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, panel

I have attached the screenshot of it.Please check this out [Panel in between two divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bB3q.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10 background-image" align="left"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2">Red division</div>
```

css

```
body{
    background-color:red;   

}
.background-image
{ 
     background: url("../img/Login-img.png") no-repeat ; 
     height:100%;
     width:80%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Here i have two divs.

1) first div for displaying the image
2)second div has the background color

Now how to add a panel for login page which is inbetween both the divs?
Please tell me some idea how to implement this?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/edc2b9ch/

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 columns.

The middle one rewrite/play(col-md-4 login-custom float) with floats on CSS

```
margin:0 right-floated-width 0 left-floated-width
```

**Example**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 background-image" align="left">
   Background Image
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 login-custom float" align="left">
        ///Add your custom floats through here for login
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  Red division
</div>
```